# Scala`s <> operator meaning

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.5

I am trying to learn Scala in order to use it with Play Framework. Now I am dealing with Play for Scala + Slick for database layer and I am using a piece of code from tutorial which I do not understand and I am unable to find any info in Scala manual.

Here is the thing. I have got model named Entry. It is defined as case class and I have a companion class extended from Table.

```
case class Entry(id: Int, name: String)

class EntryTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Entry](tag, "entries") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def * = (id, name) <> (Entry.tupled, Entry.unapply(_))
}
```

What I do not understand, is the last line with `def *`. I know, that it has something to do with reflection. Basically I would understand the part `def * = (id, name)`, but what does mean the other part. I cannot find meaning of operator `<>`? Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 9):

The operator `<>` means a projection between the tuple `(Int, String)` and case class `Entry`.

It can be explained in steps:

1. In order to return objects, Slick needs a `*` projection (`*` is from `SELECT *` in SQL)
2. This projection can be defined in various ways, but the most common is using `<>` operator. It's signature, when simplified, looks like: `<>[T, C](apply: T => C, unapply: C => Option[T])`
3. `(id, name)` constructs a tuple of `(Int, String)` (simplified, actually it's `(Rep[Int], Rep[String])`, but Slick will unlift it later)
4. `<>` maps it to `Entry`, because `Entry` has `apply` with signature `(Int, String) => Entry`, which is transformed by `.tupled` to `((Int, String)) => Entry`, and `unapply` with signature `Entry => Option[(Int, String)]`.
5. Now you have `*` projection that can construct `Entry` objects from database rows and rows from objects.

Comment: Note, that this is not standard scala thing, it is just a method with fancy name added by slick.